# Strange blockarray vertical spacing

Tags: spacing

My first question here...

Typesetting the code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{blockarray}{[ccc]}
    1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4 \\
    5 & 6 \\
  \end{blockarray}=
  \begin{blockarray}{[ccc]}
    1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4 \\
    5 & 6 \\
  \end{blockarray}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I get the following output:

[image]

My questions:

1. Why the brackets don't enclose the numbers?
2. Why the equal sign in not vertically centered?
3. Can I do something to avoid both?

Many thanks in advance.

--

kN

Answer (score 1):

Add the `\usepackage{lmodern}` package to make available the required font sizes. Also, the following is a workaround to avoid these problems, but not a real solution.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{blockarray}{[cc]c[cc]}
    1 & 2 &   &1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4 & = &3 & 4 \\
    5 & 6 &   &5 & 6 \\
  \end{blockarray}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks AboAmmar, I know it, but I actually need block array in order to do more sophisticated things, like [A|B]. I just didn't mention them to keep things simple... ;-)

Comment: So, just add the `\usepackage{lmodern}` and see the difference.

Comment: Thanks! (But it just addresses question n.1...)

Comment: Furthermore: why such a strange behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround, with a suitable `\raisebox`, and a customisation of `\bigstrut`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray, amsmath}
\usepackage{bigstrut, booktabs}
\newcommand\mybigstrut[1][4pt]{\setlength\bigstrutjot{#1}\bigstrut[t]}
\newcommand\mynegbigstrut[1][2pt]{\setlength\bigstrutjot{#1}\bigstrut[b]}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}A = \raisebox{\dimexpr(\depth-\height)\relax} {$ \begin{blockarray}{[ccc]}
    1 & 2\mybigstrut \\
    3 & 4 \\
    5 & 6 \mynegbigstrut
    \end{blockarray} $}
  \begin{blockarray}{[ccc]}
    1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4 \\
    5 & 6 \end{blockarray}
    = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4 \\
    5 & 6 \end{bmatrix} \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bernard. But my question then is: why should I _correct_ this by hand? Are these features or bugs?

Comment: Because *I* have to ;o) Seriously, I don't think it's a feature: this is a very useful package, but it  seems to have a few problems. Someone should ask the author what can be done at the package level